# Not Able to Add Quote Line Items in Field Service Lightning App

Tags: fsl

I created a Quote in Field Service Mobile App and trying to add quote line items but getting following screen.
Can anyone suggest what can be possible issue and solution.
In desktop mode there is **Add Quote Line button** available , but in FSL App getting following screen.

[image: Quote Line Items]

Comment: Do you have access to price book object?

Comment: @Vinay Yes I do have access to price book object!

Answer (score 0):

I further checked on this and I don't think you can add Quote Line Items on Field Service mobile app. Even option to create related list records for the other objects (like Service Appointment, Work Order etc.,) aren't available on the Field Service mobile app.

Kindly review limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdbcnUAB/create-related-list-records-on-field-service-mobile) and upvote.